# Printing out nested anonymous types

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml file with the following structure;

```
 <Product ID="Sample A" UserTypeID="TYPE_PRD_RANGE">
      <MultiValues>
      <Value>
       <Value AttributeId = "Att_1">Value1</Value>
      </MultiValues>
      <Values AttributeId = "Att_2">
        <Value AttributeId = "Att_3">Value1</Value>
        <Value AttributeId = "Att_4">Value2</Value>
        <Value AttributeId = "Att_5">Value3</Value>
        <Value AttributeId = "Att_6">Value4</Value>
      </Values>
      <Product ID="Sample A_1" UserTypeID="SUB_RANGE">
        <Values AttributeId = "Att_2_5">
          <Value AttributeId = "Att_2_4">Value1</Value>
          <Value AttributeId = "Att_2_3">Value2</Value>
          <Value AttributeId = "Att_2_1">Value3</Value>
          <Value AttributeId = "Att_2_2">Value4</Value>
        </Values>
      </Product>
      <Product ID="Sample A_1_1" UserTypeID="ITEM">
        <Values AttributeId = "12345">
          <Value AttributeId = "Att_2_1_1">Value1</Value>
          <Value AttributeId = "Att_2_2_1">Value2</Value>
          <Value AttributeId = "Att_2_3_1">Value3</Value>
          <Value AttributeId = "Att_2_4_1">Value4</Value>
        </Values>
      </Product>    
   </Product>
```

I have a LINQ query similar to the one below with two nested anonymous types

```
var rangeProducts = xml.Descendants("Product")
                     .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("UserTypeID") == TYPE_PRD_RANGE);

var rangeproductDetails = rangeProducts.Select(x => new
        {

            ID = (String)x.Attribute("ID"),
            UserTypeID = (String)x.Attribute("UserTypeID"),
                                Values = x.Descendants("Value")
                                .Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("AttributeID") == "Att_1" ),

            //sub group for PRD_SUB_RANGE
            descendants = x.Descendants("Product")
                         .Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("UserTypeID")=="TYPE_PRD_SUBRANGE")
                         .Select(n => new
        {
            //group for items.
            children = n.Descendants("Product")
                          .Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("UserTypeID") == "ITEM")
                          .Select(m => new
            {

                ID = (String)m.Attribute("ID"),
                UserTypeID = (String)m.Attribute("UserTypeID"),
                Values = m.Descendants("Value")
                  .Where(y =>(string)y.Attribute("AttributeID")) == "Att_2_1_1"),
            },

            //for PRD_SUB_RANGE
            ID = (String)n.Attribute("ID"),
            UserTypeID = (String)n.Attribute("UserTypeID"),
            Values = n.Descendants("Value")
              .Where(y => ((string)y.Attribute("AttributeID")) == "Att_2_4"),

        })
```

I'm trying to write out the results of the query to a console or a text file in the following format

```
"range_Product ID" ,"range_Attribute 1.Value", 
    "subrange Product_ID", "subrange_Attribute2.Value" 
        Item Product_ID,  "item_Attribute_1.Value" ,"item_Attribute_2.Value"
        Item Product_ID,  "item_Attribute_1.Value" ,"item_Attribute_2.Value"
```

Currently I'm able to do something similar to this:

```
"range_Product ID" ,"range_Attribute 1.Value", 
    "subrange Product_ID", "subrange_Attribute2.Value" 
    "subrange Product_ID", "subrange_Attribute2.Value" 
        Item Product_ID,  "item_Attribute_1.Value" ,"item_Attribute_2.Value"
        Item Product_ID,  "item_Attribute_1.Value" ,"item_Attribute_2.Value"
```

But I would like each item under each **subrange** be printed out first. Am I barking up the wrong tree here, or is this even remotely possible? I've had suggestions to simply deserialize the XMLs into POCOs but no one has been able to say if what I'm looking for is possible.

**EDIT: Sample Desired output.**

```
"Sample A"  "Value1"
  "Sample A_1"  "Value3"
     Sample A_1_1  "Value 1" "Value 2" 
     Sample A_1_2    "Value1" "Value2"
```

Comment: 1) Your XML doesn't parse: `</>Values>` should be `</Value>` and the second `<MultiValues>` should probably be `</MultiValues>`.  Can you confirm and update your question>  2) I'm a little confused as to what you want, can you give your desired output for the specific XML sample in you question?

Comment: @dbc. Ooops, You're right. I edited with sample output..

Answer (score 0):

Converting XML text output as such is definitely doable.  A couple suggestions

First, I don't see the benefit of using an anonymous type here.  having a defined top-level class to suck all of the necessary info in, IMO, would make it much easier to reason about the shape of the data you're working with.  That doesn't mean you need to serialize though; you can still manually populate the object from the XML, which is probably less work, and lets you better define end shape.

You could then associate a method with the class which outputs its data to the console in the way you see fit (even just override `ToString()`)

Also check out the extension method `XPathEvaluate`.  It will make your XML querying a lot more readable and concise.

**EDIT: Since you provided a sample of what you want, here's a solution**

```
public void OutputProductElement( XElement inElem, int inIndentLevel )
{
    string theIndentation = new string( Enumerable.Repeat( '\t', inIndentLevel ).ToArray());

    var theValueElements = inElem.XPathSelectElements( "MultiValues/Value" ).Concat(
        inElem.XPathSelectElements( "Values/Value" )
        );

    string theValueList = string.Join( " ", theValueElements.Select( elem => @"""" + elem.Value + @"""" ) );

    Console.Out.WriteLine( theIndentation + @"""" + (string)inElem.Attribute("ID") + @""" " + theValueList  );

    //no print all children elemnts
    inElem.Elements( "Product" ).ToList().ForEach( elem => OutputProductElement( elem, inIndentLevel + 1 ) );
}
```

And Here's the output:

```
"Sample A" "Value1" "Value1" "Value2" "Value3" "Value4"
  "Sample A_1" "Value1" "Value2" "Value3" "Value4"
  "Sample A_1_1" "Value1" "Value2" "Value3" "Value4"
```

Hope I didn't just do your homework for you :)

Comment: Haha, just saw your edit. It's not homework. I'm trying to create some configuration files for Tekla Warehouse and it's slow going at the moment. Could you please expansiate on "manually populating the object from XML"

Comment: I Just meant populating a class with the XML data manually, (using c# code and linq) would be just about as easy as deserialization in my mind.  But really if you're just outputing it as a string to somewhere, stuffing all of the data into a class ma be overkill, so instead, just write a recursive function like the one above ( if I'm catching your drift as far as desired output ).  Just pass in the `Root` of your XDocument and 0 for the indentation level.  Hope that helps.